# Mini "Score Keeper" Project - Having a Few Issues

Tags: javascript, project

im working on a simple score keeper app and there are a few things that are not working as intended.

https://codepen.io/Modestas/pen/LjPPVQ

Here is my part of my code:

```
if ( p1ScoreCount === inputScore.value) {
    p1Span.classList.add("green");
    gameOver = true;
    alert("Player 1 Wins!");
} 

else if ( p2ScoreCount === inputScore.value) {
    p2Span.classList.add("green");
    gameOver = true;
    alert("Player 2 Wins!");
}

if (gameOver === true) {
       p1Button.disabled = true;
       p2Button.disabled = true;
    }
```

1) Whenever the "P1Span" and "P2Span" become equal to the value of the input field, the game does not end. I even tried using a double comparison operator but still nothing.

2) Pressing the reset button only resets the input field back to its default value of 5 but does not reset the scores to 0.

3) For some reason when changing the input value by clicking the arrows (fast), there is alot of lag and the change is not always reflected in the HTML.

If anyone has any input for any of these issues i would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few simple changes

**1)** I added these validations in the click event `if(p1ScoreCount == inputScore.value) {...}`

**2)**`p1Span.innerHTML = 0; p2Span.innerHTML = 0;`

**3)** This is not necessarily a problem, it is the return time of the event `"change"`, maybe the `"click"` event is what you are looking for

```js
const p1Span = document.getElementById("p1Span");
const p2Span = document.getElementById("p2Span");
const p1Button = document.getElementById("p1");
const p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
const inputScore = document.getElementById("inputScore");
const playToSpan = document.getElementById("playToSpan");
const resetButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[2];
let gameOver = false;
let p1ScoreCount = 0;
let p2ScoreCount = 0;


// player 1/2 buttons add score to span when clicked.

p1Button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  p1ScoreCount++;
  p1Span.textContent = p1ScoreCount;
  if (p1ScoreCount == inputScore.value) {
    alert("Player 1 Win");
    p1Span.className += " green";
    p1Button.disabled = true;
    p2Button.disabled = true;
    //reset();
  }
});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  p2ScoreCount++;
  p2Span.textContent = p2ScoreCount;
  if (p2ScoreCount == inputScore.value) {
    alert("Player 2 Win");
    p2Span.className += " green";
    p1Button.disabled = true;
    p2Button.disabled = true;
  }
});

// specify what you're playing to using text input

inputScore.addEventListener("click", () => {
  playToSpan.textContent = inputScore.value;
});

// reset button resets the game

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset();
});

function reset() {
  gameOver = false;
  p1ScoreCount = 0;
  p2ScoreCount = 0;
  p1Span.innerHTML = 0;
  p2Span.innerHTML = 0;
  inputScore.value = 5;
  p1Span.classList.remove("green");
  p2Span.classList.remove("green");
  p1Button.disabled = false;
  p2Button.disabled = false;
}
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span id="p1Span">0</span> to <span id="p2Span">0</span></h1>
  <h3>Playing to: <span id="playToSpan">5</span></h3>
  <input id="inputScore" type="number" value="5">
  <button id="p1">Player One</button>
  <button id="p2">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```